# Inner join or cross join Confusion

Tags: mysql, join

For example **`select * from a inner join b on a.i=b.i` ;** is definitely inner join.

But can you let me know whether the below statements belongs to cross join or inner join ?

```
select * 
from a ,b 
where a.i=b.i;

select * 
from a ,b 
on a.i=b.i;
```

Thanks,
Kasi.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: MySQL does not care if you use or leave out `INNER` or `CROSS`.  The `ON` or `WHERE` controls things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of definition.

```
select * 
from a ,b
```

is a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
select * 
from a ,b 
where a.i=b.i;
```

is equivalent with both:

```
select * 
from a
cross join b 
where a.i=b.i;
```

and:

```
select * 
from a
inner join b 
    on a.i=b.i;
```

so in a sense, it is both an `INNER JOIN` and a `CROSS JOIN` with a filtering `WHERE` clause.

Comment: inner join performance is greater than cross join right. So select * from a inner join b on a.i=b.i; performance is better than performance of select * from a,b where a.i=b.i; Am i correct?

Comment: No, I guess most DBMS will treat then equally performance wise. The benefit of using JOIN instead of "," is clarity and maintainability. As soon as a query get more than a couple of joins - especially if join condition contains several columns - it is very easy to miss something if everything is located in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is the same as an `INNER JOIN`, the second query is not valid because it is using `ON` without a `JOIN` statement.

From a similar question:

> The comma operator is equivalent to an [INNER] JOIN operator. The
>   comma is the older style join operator. The JOIN keyword was added
>   later, and is favored because it also allows for OUTER join operations

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138355/whats-the-difference-between-comma-separated-joins-and-join-on-syntax-in-mysql)

Testing [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce4dafad97257844369ae98c5bf0848d)